# What is the rate of convergence in the uniform local limit theorem?

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-convergence, central-limit-theorem

Let $(X_i)_i$ be a sequence of iid random variables, s.t. for some sequences $a_n, b_n$ the normalized sum $$Z_n=\frac{X_1+\dots+X_n}{b_n}-a_n$$ converges weakly to an $\alpha$-stable distributed random variable $Z$ with density $q$. It is known that if $Z_n$ has a bounded density $p_n$, then we have a uniform local limit theorem
$$\Delta_n=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|p_n(x)-q(x)|\to 0.\tag{1}\label{1}$$
**Question:** What can we say about the rate of convergence $\Delta_n\to 0$?

I found a result concerning $L^p$-convergence, see [Banys 1975](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00969245?), but no asymptotic expansion or at least some large/small-o estimates for the case $p=\infty$.

I would also appreciate any comments concerning related topics, e.g. rate of convergence for the corresponding characteristic functions (since \eqref{1} is shown by Fourier-inversion).

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a problem with your second link. Please edit your post.

Answer (score 1):

(A late answer since I recently came across a similar question.)

The best result I found is by [Basu and Maejima](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Sujit_Basu2/publication/40623321_A_NON-UNIFORM_RATE_OF_CONVERGENCE_IN_A_LOCAL_LIMIT_THEOREM_CONCERNING_VARIABLES_IN_THE_DOMAIN_OF_NORMAL_ATTRACTION_OF_A_STABLE_LAW/links/0912f5141ae6416986000000.pdf):

> If the distribution of $X_1$ is absolutely continuous with density $f_{X_1}$ and belongs to the normal domain of attraction of an $\alpha$-stable random variable (strictly stable if $\alpha\in (0,1]$) with density $f_Z$, the characteristic function of $X_1$ is integrable to some power and 
>   $$
> \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{\lfloor\alpha\rfloor+1}|f_{X_1}(x) - f_Z(x)|dx<\infty,\tag{1}
> $$
>   then (with $Z_n$ as above)
>   $$
> \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}(1+|x|^{\alpha})|f_{Z_n}(x) - f_Z(x)|= O(n^{1-(1+\lfloor\alpha\rfloor)/\alpha}),\quad n\to\infty. \tag{2}
> $$

The condition (1) about existence of pseudomoment is quite restrictive. [Rachev and Yukich](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Teodosii_Rachev/publication/38361060_Rates_for_the_CLT_via_new_ideal_metrics/links/55766fa908ae7521586c3059/Rates-for-the-CLT-via-new-ideal-metrics.pdf) pose instead assumptions on some "ideal metrics". Such assumptions are weaker than (1) and are close to necessary, but I found them rather hard to verify.